# Как с помощью jQuery удалить блок с определенным html?

Tags: jquery

Есть определенное число, нужно удалить блок `$('.content')` в котором будет находиться данное число в качестве HTML.

Как пример:

```
<div class='content'>1</div>
<div class='content'>2</div>
<div class='content'>3</div>
```

P.S. Если число 2, то удаляем 2-ой блок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var content = 2;
  $(".content:contains(" + content + ")").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='content'>1</div>
<div class='content'>2</div>
<div class='content'>3</div>
<button>Delete 2</button>
```